# Transaction with WCF Async calls

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, transactions, task

I am trying to create a method as shown bellow.

```
private async void SaveAllData(Data1 data1, Data2 data2)
{
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
    {
        var task1 = _client.SaveData1Async(data1);
        var task2 = _client.SaveData2Async(data2);
        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
        transaction.Complete();
    }
}
```

I am bit doubt that whether this transaction will work?
(I already have configured wcf to support transaction)
Could you please advice me...

Comment: Have you tried it? Its the best way to see if it works! I am always surprised by how much of the .net framework is supported by WCF. In this case it should rely on the MSDTC component to work (assuming you have that installed on your environment).

Comment: Hi Aron, I have tested this, it is working fine but still I am bit lack of confident to go ahead with this.

Comment: How so? What do you need to gain confidence?

Comment: Yes. I did some more testing. Seems working fine. I will go ahead. Thanks.